# Acquiring Digital Elevation Models for Argentina from commercial providers

Tags: dem, contour, satellite, data, commercial

I'm interested in obtaining Digital Elevation Models for areas in the 20,000 acre range, as I use them to create contour maps for agriculture.

The USGS Earth Explorer has a wonderful free DEM database with world coverage, which is important to me, since I live in Argentina. Sadly, the resolution for the global dataset is too coarse, so it's useful to analyze whole countries, but not for smaller scale analysis.

So I searched the web looking for commercial satellite data providers that offer DEM files.

I found two companies that offer satellite imagery and derived products, like preprocessed DEMs, with worldwide coverage:

Airbus Defense & Space (http://www.geo-airbusds.com/worlddem-sampledata/)
BlackBridge ( http://blackbridge.com/rapideye/all-products/nextmap.html )

Of course, the data is not cheap, and, at least in the case of Airbus, they'll not take orders of less than 500 km2.

I wonder if there are any other providers of this type of data, ideally free and open, but realistically, commercial, that may be better tailored for smaller scale projects. A resolution of around 12m is perfect, but in the case of free/open sources, of course beggars can't be choosers :)

Comment: Please, specify the required resolution.

Comment: Are you after a DSM or a DTM?

Comment: I'm looking for a DTM, but I guess a DSM can be used to obtain a DTM by applying a filter, so that could be useful too if there are no alternatives.

Comment: You really should contact an Argentinian reseller of satellite imagery and DEMs. It is difficult for me to answer all your questions, without it ending up as a borderline marketing thing, which I should avoid, given the fact that I work for a reseller in a different country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the following link you'll find a good DTM of Argentina free for download - 
**http://www.ign.gob.ar/NuestrasActividades/Geodesia/ModeloDigitalElevaciones/Mapa**

Ask by phone to IGN, (the number available on the web page).

Another way: Ask in Instituto de Geodesia UBA (Av. Las Heras y Pueyrredon Buenos Aires Argentina) 3rd floor.